# What is the difference between an app dependency and a module dependency/plugin?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

When using some 3rd party libraries, I add a dependency to my module's build.gradle file.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
```

Or I add a plugin

```
    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Some other times, the library requires adding a dependency to my app's build.gradle file.

```
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

What is the difference between these dependencies and plugins?
Why can't they all be set in a single build.gradle file?

All suggestions are appreciated, I'm having trouble searching for info on this

Comment: In your third example you're talking about the `project's build.gradle` file. The app's build.gradle file is the same as the module's build.gradle file.

Answer (score 34):

Three things. There's Gradle *plugins*, module *dependencies*, and build dependencies which are placed on the *classpath of the build tool* (Gradle daemon itself).

A *plugin* is how Gradle knows what [tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) to use. There are [many plugins](https://plugins.gradle.org/). For more info, see [Gradle - Plugin Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html)

A *dependency* is [a library that is compiled with your code](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:classifiers). The following line makes your module depend on the Android AppCompat V7 library. For the most part, you search [Maven](http://mvnrepository.com/) for these.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
```

The *classpath* setting is [needed for Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html#sec:external_dependencies), not your app. For example, this allows this includes the Gradle Build Tools for Android into the classpath, and allows Gradle to build apps.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
```

> Why can't they all be in one build.gradle file?

They probably can be. It is simply more modular to not.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is meant by a task (plugins)?

Comment: Your question is entirely Gradle related, you can find all necessary references there. For example, for a Java plugin, you run the `clean` task to delete all the compiled class files.

Answer (score 16):

I got this answer from a colleague, and this helped me understand. "A gradle plugin is like the tools you use to build the app. The dependencies are the libraries included in the app. A gradle plugin is usually the tasks - like ktlint, etc."

Answer (score 4):

I didn't understand this myself so here is what i found. My answer is based on `gradle` build tool.

**Plugins:**

Add additional tasks, repositories, new DSL elements, configuration for classpaths/build/run or dependency management for subsequent development. Plugins are developed for a larger scope of development like `java`, `kotlin` or `spring-boot`.

**Dependencies:**

`modules`/libraries for tasks like `http`, `serialization` or `database` are dependencies stored remotely at `repositories` or locally that are needed at `runTime`, `test` or `build` are resolved by gradle in a configured fashion.

**Sources:**

Spring boot gradle plugin: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-gradle-plugin

Gradle documentation on plugins/dependencies: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/core_dependency_management.html

Remote repositories:
https://mvnrepository.com/

Answer (score 3):

In simple words:

**Plugins** are used to add some additonal features to the software/tools(like Gradle). Gradle will use the added plugins at the time of building the App.

**Dependecies** are used to add some addtional code to your source code, so a dependency will make some extra code (like Classes in Java) in the form of library available for your source code.