# Gradle plugin vs dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

What is the difference between adding a dependency in the `plugins` section or in the `dependencies` section?

[This](https://springframework.guru/using-project-lombok-with-gradle/) tutorial for lombok offers both, but does not give a hint on when to use which approach or if there even is a difference.

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version '3.8.4'
}
```

vs.

```
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.8'
}
```

Comment: Would this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910129/what-is-the-difference-between-an-app-dependency-and-a-module-dependency-pluginf

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I was not able to find it though... hope my title is a bit more clear and will lead more people to this explanation.

Comment: Was concerned it was a duplicate.  If you found it helpful, I have replaced it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plugins` section influences your build process.  They can control aspects of Gradle such as adding tasks, settings, how artifacts are built, publishing, etc.  These generally, unless they add `dependencies` do not affect what libraries are available to your code.  If you want to publish an artifact, for example, you could add `id 'maven-publish'` to your `plugins` and your build process would be augmented with that capability.

The `dependencies` influence your code.  They are what libraries are available to you when writing whatever code you are writing.  If you are writing Java, for example, and want to use one of the Apache Commons libraries, you would add  it to `dependencies`.

In your case, the Lombok `plugin` is adding the lombok into the `dependencies` section for you, as well as performing a few other tasks.

Comment: Thank you for claryfing, that's a good summary!

Answer (score 2):

- Plugin -> code that runs as part of the build
- Dependency -> code that forms part of the program you are building with Gradle